# How to open just 10% magnified jpeg image in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I want to apply a background foreground segmentation to a Jpeg image. The algorithm is called Grabcut and the code is available online. My image is 4896*3264 pixels. The problem is when I pass the image into the code, it opens the image 100% magnified as the input, which is too big for my computer screen to view. Actually the program is interactive where I need to mark an area over the object in the image that I want to extract and so the image opens as an input. The code is written in python. Can anyone tell me, how to open say just 10% magnified image? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [resize()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
rows, cols = image.shape[:2]

resized = cv2.resize(image, (cols / 10, rows / 10), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

You can display `resized` and allow the user to select a region on it, then map the coordinate of that region back to the original image so you can do the actual processing on the full size image.

Comment: But, won't it resize the image? I mean decrease the quality of the image.

Comment: You can keep two versions of the image, the original for doing high quality processing, and the resized one for viewing.

Comment: The best thanks is pressing the accept button on the answer :-)